# Assigning an array of pixels to GTK# DrawingArea

Tags: c#, user-interface, mono, gtk

I have an byte[] of raw pixel data. How can I access the pixels of a GTK# DrawingArea and assign the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] pixels = new byte[width * height * 4];
// ...
Gdk.GC gc = new Gdk.GC(drawingArea.GdkWindow);
drawingArea.GdkWindow.DrawRgb32Image(gc, 0, 0, width, height, RgbDither.None, pixels, width * 4);
```